# Can any one tell me how to use services for various

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Can any one tell me how to use services for media player for playing the songs in background.

Comment: And you have read the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any services to play song in the background . Internally media player calls its services and plays the song in the background.

Comment: I was tempted to write the same, but actually this is not a totally correct answer in itself, because it has an underlying assumption: Namely that anku wants to have an Activity at all. But it is possible that he wants to trigger a MediaPlayer event-based through an IntentService. Hence, I refrained from giving this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If reading through the reference and understanding [Media Player](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) is too much trouble check this.

[Android Building Audio Player Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/)

Comment: why hive projects not working on real device....